# Value of divergent series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a positive, convergent sequence. We consider the sequence of partial sum $\{s_n\}: s_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_n$. Clearly $\{s_n\}$ is strictly increasing and therefore $\sum_{n=1}^\infty s_n$ diverges to $\infty$.

Here's the problem: we want to calculate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n$. Since $a_n = s_n - s_{n-1}$, we have:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n(s_n-s_{n-1}) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty ns_n - \sum_{n=1}^\infty ns_{n-1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty ns_n - \sum_{n=1}^\infty (n+1)s_n = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty s_n$

Thus $\sum_{n=1}^\infty s_n = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n$. This doesn't make sense since we can make the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n$ converge, while $\sum_{n=1}^\infty s_n$ should still diverge. Also, both $\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty s_n$ should be $\geq 0$.

Anything wrong with the above argument?

Comment: A nitpick/sidenote: you have some notational inconsistencies between $\sum_k$ vs $\sum_n$  I know this is probably a typo, but just wanted to bring it up in case you were directly copying from your work. :)

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^\infty na_n$ diverges as well, as $\ge \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_n$.

Comment: @anorton Thank you for noticing. I've corrected the notation.

Comment: @Berci If we pick $a_n = \frac{1}{n^3}$ woudn't the series converge?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the part where you write $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(s_n-s_{n-1}) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty ns_n - \sum_{n=1}^\infty ns_{n-1}$. Both "sums" on the right diverge.

Comment: More specifically, the assertion: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n + \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n + b_n)$ is only guaranteed to be true if both the sums $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ converge individually. Or more generally if any two of the series $\sum a_n$, $\sum b_n$ and $\sum (a_n + b_n)$ then so does the third.

Comment: Since both of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty ns_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty ns_{n-1}$ diverge, you cannot use that identity.

Comment: Thank you @André Nicolas @Joel! That make sense. Quick question: if we assume both series are convergent and use this identity to reach some contradiction, can we conclude that the assumption is false? (And thus this might be a tool for testing whether a series diverges?)

Comment: @s6b4: Yes, the inference would be correct. And the idea you mention in the comment above can be used, for example, to prove that $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots$ diverges.